# Show $\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{1}{y}\int_0^y f(x) dx=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and satisfy $\displaystyle\ \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=:L\in \mathbb R.$

Then, prove

・ $f$ is bounded on $[0,\infty)$

・ $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to\infty}\ \dfrac{1}{y^2}\int_0^y f(x) dx=0$

・ $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to\infty}\ \dfrac{1}{y}\int_0^y f(x) dx=L.$

I proved the boundedness of $f$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{y\to\infty}\ \dfrac{1}{y^2}\int_0^y f(x) dx=0$, but I didn't solve the third problem.

---

Let $\epsilon>0$.

$\exists R>0 ; x\geqq R\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon.$

Define some $y_0:=\cdots$.

When $y\geqq y_0$, 
\begin{align}
\left|\dfrac{1}{y}\int_0^y f(x) dx-L \right|
&\leqq
\dfrac{1}{y}\int_0^y \left|f(x)-L \right|dx\\
&=
\dfrac{1}{y}\left(\underset{=:M}{\underline{\int_0^R \left|f(x)-L \right|dx}}+\int_R^y \left|f(x)-L \right|dx\right)\\
&\leqq \dfrac{1}{y}(M+(y-R)\epsilon)\\
&=\dfrac{M}{y}+\left(1-\dfrac{R}{y}\right)\epsilon
\end{align}

Am I on right track ? I don't know how I should proceed from here. Thanks for any help. (We have to note that $R$ and $M$ is dependent on $\epsilon.$)

Comment: $(1 - \frac{R}{y}) \epsilon < \epsilon$, so we need to bound $\frac{M}{y}$ by some constant multiple of $\epsilon$.  Remember that $f$ has been shown to be bounded, and $y_0$ can be dependent on $\epsilon$ and $R$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: I take $y_0:=M/\epsilon.$ Then $M/y+(1-R/y)\epsilon<M/y+\epsilon\leqq M/y_0+\epsilon=2\epsilon.$ O.K.? @L.F.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the limit for $\epsilon/2$ there is an $M>0$ such

that : $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon /2$ for $x>M$. Therefore

$(-\epsilon /2+L)(y-M)<\int_{M}^{y}f(x)dx<(+\epsilon /2+L)(y-M)$.

Dividing by $y$ we obtain

$(-\epsilon /2+L)(y-M)/y<\int_{M}^{y}f(x)dx/y<(+\epsilon /2+L)(y-M)/y$.

There is also an $N>0$ such that for $y>N$ we have

$ -\epsilon /2<\int_{0}^{M}f(x)dx/y\,\,<\epsilon /2$. Adding the two

inequalities we get

$ (-\epsilon+L)-(\epsilon/2+L)M/y<\int_{0}^{y}f(x)dx/y<\epsilon+L-(M/y)(\epsilon/2+L)$.

By the last inequality we obtain

$(-\epsilon+L)-(\epsilon/2+L)M/y<\int_{0}^{y}f(x)dx/y<\epsilon+L$.

By taking $y>K>N>0$ where K is sufficiently large, we can have

$|M/y|<\epsilon^2/(\epsilon/2\,+L)$ and it easy to get

$-\epsilon/2+L-\epsilon^2<\int_{0}^{y}f(x)dx/y<\epsilon+L$ and hence

$-\epsilon+L<\int_{0}^{y}f(x)dx/y<\epsilon+L$ which gives that the

r.h.s also tends to $L$.